# Api Request from the .dll / .aspx file in HTML/js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-framework-7

I need to request an api from the .dll / .aspx file.

I don't know in what way it is encrypted exactly. I just have the file and the method names . How do i make a request?

When i try to access using ajax method

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "auth.aspx/Login",  
    data: "{email:'abc', password:'213'}",  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(msg) {   
        alert("success: " + msg);  
    }
});
```

i got the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Ganeshk/Desktop/cordova%20app%20crm%20new/ajax/auth.aspx/Login. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear; you cannot make an AJAX request to the local file system, in this case your C:/ drive. You need to make the request to a webserver, either local or remote. If you're developing in ASP.Net you can make the request to the local web server instance which Visual Studio spins up when you press F5 to run the site by default.

Also note that the data you're sending is not in the correct format, you should send provide it to the property in an object, like this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "auth.aspx/Login",  
    data: {
        email: 'abc', 
        password: '213' // I assume this will be coming from a user input
    },  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(msg) {   
        alert("success: " + msg);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually in the aspx file it is referring to web service.

Comment: Same logic applies. You need to either use the full remote URL of the web service, or run it on a local server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually That is my question, How to make the reference. i had referred my .aspx file location.